# Vue / Vuetify wrapping to columns based on screen

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a parent component that inside of it, I use a `v-for` to render `product-box` component based on the number of products.  Right now, if I have 200 products, they just stack one on top of the other which extends the page length like this:

```
[box]
[box2]
[box3]
[box4]
--page bottom--
```

Instead of having the page length keep increasing, can I have it where it wraps based on the window size like this:

```
[box1]  [box3]
[box2] [box4]
--page bottom--
```

or if I move the screen even smaller:

```
[box1]  [box2] [box3] [box4]
--page bottom--
```

**Parent component**

```
<div>
    <product-box 
        v-for="(product,index) in this.$store.getters.getProducts"
        :key="index"
        :product = product
    >
    </product-box>
</div>
```

---

**ProductBox.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class='products-box-component'>
        <v-row>
            <v-col cols="12">
                <v-row
                >
                    <v-col cols="2" :class="{'products-box': true}">
                            <div class="image-container">
                            </div>
                            <div class="info-container">
                            </div>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: use `inline` or `inline-block` elements? There are many solutions to this problem. This is solely a CSS solution though, Vue is not related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the component you're currently using.
i think consider using a `grid` layout.

```css
.app-list-container {
  // grid http://www.ruanyifeng.com/blog/2019/03/grid-layout-tutorial.html
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: space-around;
  // justify-content:center;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 60px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 60px);
   // grid-row-gap: 10px;
   // grid-column-gap: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class='app-list-container'>
  <div v-for="(product,index) in this.$store.getters.getProducts"
      :key="index"
      class="app-item"
      >
  </div>
</div>
```

当然这种需求最简单的就是CSS来搞定